# Is Login and Sign Up put together secure?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, authentication, passwords

Haven't begun writing any code, so this is not language specific.
In many websites when you click login, there will be another link down the bottom to sign up if you don't have an account.

I have an idea for a login page where you enter your email, and in the background (without any reloading), it checks whether that email is linked to an account.

If you do not have an account it adds all the relevant fields (DOB, name, confirm password). But if it detects you do have an account, it will just leave the single password field.

**The question is:**
Is this secure having these two pages built into one, and is there any main reason most websites have the two login and s

Answer (score 1):

It is secure to put both forms (sign in and sing up) on the same page, or alternatively to put both operations in the same form.

The only security issue it produces is that malicious users would know whether or not a specific username exists in your website, and that way it would be a little bit easier for them to break into a random account, but it is relatively not such a big deal. I wouldn't take it into account in terms of security.

Nevertheless, the main issue regarding having both sing in and sign up in the same form is a UX issue. It might be confusing for the user what the purpose of the form is. Having a clear sign up page is crucial in order not to loose potential customers.

Anyway, in order to make your sign-up and sign-in forms secured, you should learn all the following topics: TLS, XSS, CSRF, JWT, Clickjacing, Challenge-Response authentication, SQL injenction, replay attack, Captcha, Encryption and Salting, as well as keeping track with the new vulnerabilities that are getting published.

Comment: Malicious users could just use the sign in field and when met with "username already exists", figure out usernames the same. You make a good point about UX though.

Comment: @OliverMurfett you're right, although nowadays many websites choose not to tell you if you type an incorrect password or the username doesn't exist at all. They just leave you a message like "Your username or password is incorrect".